# Read Sibling Data of a particular node using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase realtime database and  Firebase cloud functions(in Typescript).
Below is the structure of my database nodes:

Orders Node:

```
orders
|- {Push ID}
    |--billing_id
    |--orders_id
```

Shippings Node:

```
shippings
|- {Push ID}
    |-- billing_id
    |-- user_id
```

My function observes changes on the "orders" node and fetches the value of the "billing_id".

> Note: This billing_id is the same billing_id that is stored in a
> "shippings" node. This billing_id will always be present in the "shippings" node.

In the next step I want to target the shippings node containing the exact billing_id and fetch the user_id.
Below is the code(shortest version):

```
export const orderEmail = functions.database.ref('/orders/{pushId}')
.onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{
    const original = snapshot.val(); //Stores values from the newly created orders node
    const billing_id = original.billing_id; // Stores the billing_id from the newly created orders node

//Need help from here.
    var db = admin.database();
    var val1:any;
    db.ref(`/shippings/{pushId}/${billing_id}`).once("value") //Next what do I need to do?
});
```

**Edit 1:**

Tried the solution suggested by Neelavar. Below are the warnings and errors that I'm getting while deploying the function.

```
WARNING: A:/HN/functions/src/index.ts:79:9 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: A:/HN/functions/src/index.ts:79:13 - Identifier 'db' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: A:/HN/functions/src/index.ts:86:24 - Shadowed name: 'snapshot'
WARNING: A:/HN/functions/src/index.ts:149:9 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: A:/HN/functions/src/index.ts:149:13 - Identifier 'options' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RIYASREE'S_PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-15T14_18_07_047Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

> NOTE: Please let me know if any other info is needed.
> Also, please provide a detailed solution for this as I am new to both Firebase and Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Neelavar's help and a little bit of tweaking the code I was able to successfully fetch the desired value. Below is the running code:

```
export const orderEmail = functions.database.ref('/orders/{pushId}')
.onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{
    const original = snapshot.val(); //Stores values from the newly created orders node

const billing_id = original.billing_id; // Stores the billing_id from the newly created orders node
        var db = admin.database();
        var val1:any;
       return db.ref(`/shippings`)
              .orderbyChild('billing_id')
              .equalTo(billing_id).once("value", snap:any => {
    const data = snap.val();
    const pushId = Object.keys(data)[0]; //Gets the Push Id
    const userId = data[pushId].user_id; // Gets the user_id
    console.log("User Id", userId)
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the `billing_id` from the `onCreate` trigger, now you need to query the `shippings` node for the known `billing_id`.

```
    db.ref(`/shippings`)
          .orderbyChild('billing_id')
          .equalTo(billing_id).once("value", snapshot => {
           // Now use the snapshot to access the shippings collection document
           // which now has both billing_id and user_id - only with matching billing_id

    });
```

Comment: Hey! I am getting errors. Could you please check again?
I'm editing my question with the error messages..

Comment: If you have typescript strict check enabled, then use `.once("value", (snapshot: any) => {`